# What regions worldwide have not been conquered or colonized by nations recursively located in land once ruled by someone born in Belgium?

Tags: europe, war

I'm working on an alternate history book based on historical events. Basically, the group of tribes from the Roman era that are grouped under the Belgae group managed to avoid being conquered by the Romans, remained a nation during the Germanic invasions at the end of the Roman Empire and then started forming a global empire. Basically, take the below map (courtesy of Wikipedia), but everything between the English Channel, Paris, the Rhine and the Moselle is not part of the Franchi, but part of this Belgae nation:

[image]

After this time, any time someone born in an area part of Belgium at the time of birth went on to conquer another region in our timeline, that region would remain a part of Belgium permanently and would never be conquered again by any other nation, nor would any rebellions or other nations rise in that area.

Now, my knowledge of historical events is not that good, but I did find that the Merovingian dynasty and the Carolingian Dynasty were born right in the middle of that region, which means that Belgium would rather quickly have control over France and the Holy Roman Empire. Add to that the Reconquista, the invasion of England by Normandy and the Crusades. From what I can tell, most of Western and Central Europe would have been part of Belgium by the 1400s. This means that all colonies also would have become part of Belgium.

I'm not sure how much of the world would be part of the Belgian Empire. That is the biggest blind spot in the story right now: **what areas were not conquered or colonized by a power recursively located in land once ruled by someone who was born in the Belgae tribe area?** From what I can find, China, Japan and Korea are the most prominent in this category. I'm not sure about Russia: it has been invaded multiple times, but as far as I know, none of those invasions had any real success, with Russia fighting a war of attrition and retreat until the invaders were forced to pull back.

---

I see that many people among you comment on how certain aspects of my question are extremely unlikely, like the fact that noone revolts against the Belgians, or that the Belgians wouldn't work like that because they don't share an identity, or that this is a question about alternate history and thus shouldn't belong here.

About the alternate history part: I'm not asking about alternate history. I'm asking about how the actual history of our world goes so I can build a better backstory to my book, because many of the events in our world also happen in the book, just with different countries. For example, the Crusades still happen. So do the Colonial periods, the Mongol Horde and the Viking invasions. the only difference with out world is that some of the later crusades to reconquer lost holy land don't happen, the Colonies don't become independent and the invasions fail at the border of the Belgian empire.

The rebellions and uprisings: I worded that badly. They do happen, but they're struck down rather fast. There are no sucessful rebellions or uprisings.

Belgium not working like that: In the book, Belgians have a unique feat called Ancestral Guidance (https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9932/what-consequences-would-ancestral-guidance-have) which gives them an edge over other groups and gives them an identity. This feat is hereditary and rapidly spreads to newly conquered regions, while not going anywhere beyond the border.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26079/discussion-on-question-by-nate-kerkhofs-what-regions-worldwide-have-not-been-con).

Comment: Not a full answer, but Antarctica and international waters arguably meet your requirements. There are also plenty of places on Earth that one government or another claims, but aren't really "conquered", like a number of uninhabited islands worldwide, inland Greenland, Svalbard, many high alpine regions.

Comment: It all really depends on how you define "conquered". Is a place really conquered just because some European planted a flag there? Can a Belgian child "conquer" the world simply by declaring themselves the ruler of the world? Ownership is not a natural property, but one that arises from people interacting with other people. If you're going to give ownership magical properties, you need to very clearly define what you mean first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is absolutely zero. The Belgae people of 50 BC and the Belgians of today are in all likelihood completely genetically different - the area was resettled by Romans, as you say, but also suffered (and most likely bred with) various different Germans, Goths, Huns, Magyars and finally Vikings before we reach somewhere resembling today's modern Belgians.

If your question is "What have the people who have lived in the area conquered throughout history" then you could say the whole world (you did mention recursively) because the people in the region became French, Normans and Dutch, who then became other states like the UK, the USA, etc.

Although by the 1400's no French, Norman English or Flemish king has ever sat on the throne of:

- Any Kingdom in Spain
- Northern Italy
- Poland
- Hungary
- Russia
- Scandinavia

Comment: Sure enough. But don't forget Charles V.... ;)

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Doesn't count, he's German by house so he wouldn't be born if the Hapsburg never inherited/conquered Burgundy :P

Comment: I doubt they'd have conquered the whole world. As I mentioned, at least China, Korea and Japan would have remained independant since they were never conquered or colonized by a European nation.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Japan was conquered by the United States, who also took control of South Korea as a Japanese colony. Nearly all of North Korea was occupied during the Korean War. During the First Opium War, the British took Canton. By your rules that makes Canton forever a part of Belgium, and Canton later formed the National Revolutionary Army which conquered all of China Proper.

Comment: And what about Russia beyond the areas conquered by France during the Napoleon Era? Napoleon only conquered Russia up until Moscow AFAIK. apart from the Mongols, has any other nation ever conquered sizeable parts of Siberian Russia?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs probably not, but if Napoleon conquered Russia and Russia now owns Siberia, by extension that makes Siberia Belgian too due to your recursive clause?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine That depends on whether Siberia was under Russian control already when Napoleon conquered it. If Russia already controlled it, it stays under Russian control. That can actually help my plot along, since I would like to have a later part happen in a location that's not in the Empire. If Russia only gained control over it AFTER the Napoleon invasion, it would also be conquered. The important part is whether Russia had officially announced a claim on Siberia yet.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Oh in that case then yes it was already under Russian control. But later on the Bolsheviks, who are largely from Moscow, 're-conquer' Russia in the Russian Civil War.

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine I'm not sure. it depends on the leader of the Bolsheviks at the time of that civil war and where they were born. The general idea is that the birthplace of the leader of a revolution or conquest determines whether their conquest is successfull, because of the ancestral bonuses granted by being born in land that belongs to Belgium. From my research, the leader of the Bolsheviks was Lenin, who was born in Simbirsk, which appears to not have been conquered by Napoleon at the time.

Comment: Nice answer, except that the current ruling dinasty in Spain are the Borbons, of indisputable French origin (google "Spanish Sucesion war". And Bernadotte became King of Sweden.

Comment: In the "recursive" setting of this question, since Merovingians were born in Belgium, the Frankish empire qualifies as "Belgium" and any place ruled by people born there is "Belgium". The Iberian Peninsula qualifies (through the counts of Barcelona, at least) and the whole British Empire too (through William the Conqueror).

Comment: @Evil Washing Machine - Emperor Charles V was born in 1500 in Ghent, part of the county of Flanders, which was divided between the Kingdom of France and the Holy Roman Empire.  Anyway it is part of modern Belgium and part of your greater Belgium.   Therefore any place ever ruled by Spain counts, and any place every claimed by Spain counts.

Comment: I note that Emperor Henry VI was born in Nijmegen on the river Waal and thus close to the borders of your Belgium.  If he counts then he was king of Germany, Italy, & Burgundy which puts every place ever colonized by Germany, Italy, France, the Netherlands or Belgium within your Belgium empire. King Richard I of England was alleged to become Henry's vassal, making the future British empire part of your Belgium empire.  Emperor Henry conquered Sicily, became overlord of Cyprus and Armenia, and extorted tribute from the Byzantine empire.

Comment: Emperor Henry VI forced Emperor Alexius III to pay him tribute.  The Byzantine empire of Alexius III included all the future capitals of the Ottoman realm.  The Ottomans became the overlords of the Khanate of Crimea from 1745 to 1774.  The Khans of Crimea occassionially claimed the Mongol tribute from Russia and didn't give up the claim until 1700, by which time Russia had conquered Siberia.

Comment: Emperor Henry VII was born in Valenciennes, county of Hainault, in your Belgium, about 1275.  Emperor Charles VII was born in Brussels, in your Belgium in 1697.  Pepin of Landin (c. 580-640) was born in Belgium and became Mayor of Austrasia,  Peipin of Heristal was born at Heristal in belgium and became Mayor of all three Frankish kingdoms.and ancestor of Charlemagne.  Thus every place ever ruled by Germany, France, the Netherlands, or Belgium would be part of your Belgium empire.